# How can I make divs one below the other with the html and css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making a page and I need one div block to go under the other. I have a lot of different color divs, and when I use margin-top:100px(for example) for one div, and margin-top:200px for other div it looks ok on my computer but on the lap top completely different

--- 1st and 2nd divs are in the right place, but I have to put the 3rd one below the 2nd div. How can I do that?
Here is the pic:

[image]

Comment: @Hey, the image link seems like has expired.

Comment: I've change it. I hope you can see it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your divs to "position:relative", then set z-index properties. The lower it's set the farther it's displayed...

Example :

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Then your css :

```
.div1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.div2 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f90;
}
.div3 {
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    margin-top: -100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
  width:500px;  
}
.innerdivs
{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="innerdivs" style="background-color:#4C4C4C;"><h1>first div</h1></div>
  <div class="innerdivs" style="background-color:#0087DE;"><h1>2nd div</h1></div>
  <div class="innerdivs" style="background-color:#FFFF00;"><h1>3rd div</h1></div>
</div>
```

that is working perfectly in here

Answer (score 0):

I have added 3 different Div's with different colors one after another with 100% width. So it works without overlapping div's in mobile screens as well.

```
   #container {

  width:100%;
  display:block;

 }

.content1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background:pink; 
display:flex;
}
.content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
  display:flex;
}
.content3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
  display:flex;
}
```

[image]

http://jsbin.com/nonufehuja/4/edit

If you want to add margin to entire page container

```
#container {

  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-top:100px
 }
```

http://jsbin.com/nonufehuja/5/edit

Margin for second div

```
.content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
  display:flex;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nonufehuja/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#wrapper{
  width:100%;  
  max-width:460px;
}
.inline-divs
{
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  }
#div1{
 height:50px;
 background-color:#ff0000;
}

#div2{
 height:150px;
 background-color:#00ff00;
}

#div3{
 height:300px;
 background-color:#0000ff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inline-divs" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="inline-divs" id="div2"></div>
  <div class="inline-divs" id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/1tuj0c9a/2/

Hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [CSS z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property

For example, in styles, for div1 you should add

```
position:relative;
    z-index:1;
```

For div2

```
position:relative;
    z-index:2;
```

For div3

```
position:relative;
        z-index:3;
```